# Bought Ether from ethereum presale (genesis) Forgot password

Tags: ether, presale, recovery, genesis

I bought ethereum from the presale. I have the json file but unfortunately forgot the password. Is there a way I can access the wallet?

Comment: So it may be possible to brute force the password depending on how bad it was and what you can remember. The ETH guys are *not* obliged to help you with this. However if the amount of money is large you may be able to find a whitehat who will help you.

Answer (score 2):

No.

From the Ethereum presale message:

> You are about to make an ether purchase. Please keep the attached wallet file safe. It will serve as a cryptographic receipt of your purchase, along with your password.
>
> The password you created and entered on the sale site is the key to your ether so please do not forget it. And please note: there are no mechanisms in place that will enable the Ethereum team to help you recover a lost password. Once it is lost, your purchased ether will be permanently inaccessible.